# Magento: Price Field in Adminhtml product form

Tags: php, magento, adminhtml

I would like to add a price field into my admin form under my product edit page, but I cannot add a “price” type into my fieldset.

```
$fieldset->addField($attribute->getAttributeCode(), 'price', array(
             'label'     => Mage::helper('mymod')->__($attribute->getFrontendLabel()),
             'class'     => $attribute->getIsRequired()?'required-entry':'',
             'required'  => $attribute->getIsRequired()?true:false,
             'name'      => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
             'note'     => Mage::helper('mymod')->__($attribute->getNote()),
        ));
```

it is giving the following error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Price' not found in .. /lib/Varien/Data/Form/Abstract.php on line 144
```

PS. 
I am digging the code in

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
```

where in function

```
_setFieldset
```

It can use the price as fieldType.

**Edit @ 11/6:**

Digging into _setFieldset(), from the first line

```
$this->_addElementTypes($fieldset);
```

will invoke an implementable function

```
function _getAdditionalElementTypes()
```

to add additional data type (such as price, gallary..) not in the given list.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just just have to do `text` because these are the available options:

```
Button
Checkbox
Checkboxes
Collection
Column
Date
Editor
Fieldset
File
Gallery
Hidden
Image
Imagefile
Label
Link
Multiline
Multiselect
Note
Obscure
Password
Radio
Radios
Reset
Select
Submit
Text
Textarea
Time
```